# Animation for named routes

Tags: android, animation, routes, flutter

In Flutter we can customize the view-change animation by extending `PageRoute` (or by using a class which extends that).

For instance, I'm changing the animation to "slide" in my `MaterialApplication` by using the `CupertinoPageRoute` that way:

```
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
  CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (context) => Calendar()),
);
```

Now I want to change that by using named views defined in the `main.dart` file:

```
return MaterialApp(
  title: 'Demo',
  theme: myTheme, // => Theme.of(context).copyWith(...)
  initialRoute: '/',
  routes: {
    '/': (context) => Login(),
    '/calendar': (context) => Calendar(),
  }
);
```

This way I can just call

```
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/calendar');
```

Which is IMO clearer and view-agnostic.

The issue with this approach is that I can't define a `PageRoute`, so I can't customize the view-change animation.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I took chemamolins' advice and solved it in a similar way, but using maps.

I "extracted" the `routes` object and put it outside `MaterialApp`:

```
var routes = {
  '/': (context) => Login(),
  '/calendar': (context) => Calendar()
};
```

Then I used it inside `onGenerateRoute`:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  var routes = {
    '/': (context) => Login(),
    '/calendar': (context) => Calendar()
  };

  return MaterialApp(
    title: 'Demo',
    theme: myTheme,
    initialRoute: '/',
    onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
      return CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (context) => routes[settings.name](context));
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Any explainations for the downvote would be appreciated.

Comment: Great, but how do you call a page with a specific animation? By calling this: `Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/register'); ` I just get a slide left animation, but what if I want to change that to slide up/right/....?

Comment: @Paul `CupertinoPageRoute` and `MaterialPageRoute` are built to behave the same as how native applications would, so there is no way to customize the animation direction. You can however [build your own animation](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/animation/page-route-animation) and make it exactly as needed.

Comment: The problem is that I couldn't find an opportunity to do **custom animations with named routes**.  Animation with your link: `pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => const Page2()` Is there a way to call the next page with the route-name?

Answer (score 2):

You could leverage `onGenerateRoute()`

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  Route onGenerateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    Route page;
    switch (settings.name) {
      case "/":
        page = CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (context) => Login());
        break;
      case "/calendar":
        page = CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (context) => Calendar());
        break;
    }
    return page;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new WidgetsApp(
      onGenerateRoute: onGenerateRoute,
      initialRoute: "/",
    );
  }
}
```

Let's give a look to the Flutter code itself.

There is a framework provided `onGenerateRoute()` method called to generate the routes.

Look at the following snippet taken from the app.dart file in the framework.

```
  Route<dynamic> _onGenerateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    final String name = settings.name;
    WidgetBuilder builder;
    if (name == Navigator.defaultRouteName && widget.home != null) {
      builder = (BuildContext context) => widget.home;
    } else {
      builder = widget.routes[name];
    }
    if (builder != null) {
      return new MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>(
        builder: builder,
        settings: settings,
      );
    }
    if (widget.onGenerateRoute != null)
      return widget.onGenerateRoute(settings);
    return null;
  }
```

If the `routes:` provides a builder for a given name, it is used to generate the route using `MaterialPageRoute` by default. If it is not provided, it goes to generate it by using your `onGenerateRoute()` method.

Comment: Isn't that a bit of a hack? I mean, what is the purpose of defining routes if I have to define them again in the `onGenerateRoute` method?

Comment: I don't think it's a hack if you want to use named routes. In the `routes:` property you can't customize the route, you can just set the widget through the builder. By contrast, in `onGenerateRoute()` you can customize the `Route`. Let's say that `routes:` is the shortcut for `onGenerateRoute:` when you want to use default `MaterialPageRoute`.

Comment: I have edited my answer to explain why this is not a hack if what the `routes:` property provides is not enough for you.

Comment: Got it. I did it this way, but using a map rather than a switch-case. Thanks